# Why is Secret Wars kept secret?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars

I mean, when the Earths from multi-universes collide with each other and everything is in danger, the heroes in Illuminati try to figure out how to save the world, in secret. However, under this situation, isn't the most reasonable thing to do is publicizing this message and evacuating the people lives on Earth to other places as soon as possible?

Using the Bifrost of Asgards, applying transport magic of Doctor Strange, borrowing spaceships from alien allies, there are many ways available. Also there are countless planets in universe habitable (for example, Xandar). After all human evacuated, the Earth can be safely bombed out. This could be achieved if all human work together, so why do heroes keep all thing secret?

Comment: "All humans work together" - Have you met humans?

Comment: Humans fought over toilet-paper when things got a little messy. Are we gonna suddenly be united?

Comment: best comments ever, they should be accepted answers